# Arm Debug Interface vs CoreSight infrastructure in Cortex-M

Tags: arm

Both documents define standards for communicating with DAP.

The information seems contradictory.

Slide 4 [of this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/AnhDungNGUYEN3/aame-tc2013-004v02-debug-and-optimization) says `Debug features of Cortex-M4 are compliant with ARMv7 debug architecrute (CoreSight based)` which to me implies that CoreSight is some lower level on which arm debug architecture is build.

But [Arm official website](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/debug-visibility-and-trace/coresight-architecture) makes it look like CoreSight is actually build **on top** of Arm Debug Interface v6. Because the spec for ADI is included as part of CoreSight overview.

Different page on [Arm official website](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/debug-visibility-and-trace) says that CoreSight is based on `The debug and trace architectures` which to me implies that CoreSight is build on top of ADI.

The [CoreSight white paper](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.epm039795/coresight_technical_introduction_EPM_039795.pdf) appears to mention the same things as Arm Debug Interface: DAP, SWJ-DP, etc. Which makes me thing that it is the same specification as Arm Debug Interface, but maybe just renamed, or the draft version.

But [Arm Debug Interface v6](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0074/a/debug_interface_v6_0_architecture_specification_IHI0074A.pdf?_ga=2.41936353.256456825.1554145572-24350261.1554145572) seems to imply that these are possibly compatible but different technologies:

> Compatibility between CoreSight and ARM debug interfaces:
>
> ADIv6 is compatible with the ARM CoreSight architecture:
>
> • ADIv6 can be used to access and control CoreSight-compatible components.
>
> • The ADIv6 specification does not require debug components to comply with the CoreSight architecture.

After looking at the above sources I just feel more confused :)

**Question:** How do they relate to each other? Is one of them an expansion of the other?

Comment: Questions here need to be *specific* and *stand alone* - ie, clicking on links cannot be a requirement to determine what you are trying to ask.  What **actual concrete conflicts** have you found in those sources of information?  **What actual problem are you trying to solve?**  You certainly aren't licensing the core to put in your own silicon...

Comment: I added more details. I do not have an actual problem to solve, but I am starting development for cortex-M and trying to understand the different pieces that ARM provides and how they relate.

Comment: If you only develop firmware then you don't really need to care about all of this, J-Link/Ozone/gdb/Eclipse/whatever takes care of this already. I think you would need to know the details at that level if you were making really performance-critical firmware, or your own debugger, or a new debug probe, or a new chip. The only practical "difference" I've encountered is that the firmware on a Cortex-M0 can't easily discover if a debugger is connected.

Comment: From what I've seen, the CoreSight 20 pin header has 5 more active pins that are used for TRACE (clock + 4 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, you can think of ADI as a part of CoreSight.

> The CoreSight architecture provides a system-wide solution for real-time debug and collecting trace information.

There are many types of CoreSight components, the most familiar of which is probably AP/DP, the component you use to access debugging resources. ADI provides specifications for the AP/DP components and in particular how to access them.

The ADI implementation is sometimes referred to as DAP.

---

Now, let's go back to CoreSight and ADI:

**1. ADIv6 can be used to access and control CoreSight-compatible components**

Yes, ADIv6 itself is part of the CoreSight architecture.

**2. The ADIv6 specification does not require debug components to comply with the CoreSight architecture**

Yes, you can use this to access other parts of the system.

---

Considering that you mentioned Cortex-M, I would like to remind you that most Cortex-M architectures use ADIv5, including:

- Cortex-M0
- Cortex-M3
- Cortex-M4
- Cortex-M7
- Cortex-M23
- Cortex-M33

For ADIv5, they also have several minor version. Please check the corresponding technical reference manual, which indicates the specific version they use.

The Cortex-M55 from 2020 onwards uses ADIv6. **Note that ADIv5 and ADIv6 use different DP and AP specifications: the DP is somewhat similar, but the AP is fundamentally different.**